# Should I use posts or pages in this scenario?

Tags: posts, categories, pages, tags

I'm considering using WordPress as the CMS for the website of a small clinic. There are only two sections with sub-sections: team and methods.

Team contains each of the team members and Methods contains all of the treatment methods the clinic offers. Each method is linked to one or more team members, and each team member is linked to one or more methods.

As an example, if a visitor clicks on Team they should be presented with an overview list of all team members, each with a small portrait and a short version of their bio. The visitor then clicks on a particular team member and is taken to their full bio. The bio includes a full-size portrait, the full bio text, and links to each method the team member practices (e.g. physio therapy, acupuncture, shiatsu etc.)

What's the best way to organize this? Should each team member be a post of the category Team or a child page of Team? What about the methods? Should tags be used in this case?

Answer (score 1):

That's easy.

Each method is a post with a category.
Member list is a page listing members (also pages).

Fore each team member, add custom field containing category names.
Then just list post containing those categories for each member.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but what about each method showing the team members who practice it?

Comment: Just list all pages that has custom fields containing the current post categories (merge them into one string). Just make sure the ordering of the categories matches the custom field string. Or you could look into custom posts -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types.